# Visual Studio Express 2013. Package Failed

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have encountered the following error message after finishing Visual Studio Express 2013 installation 
[image]

And here's what I have found out in the log file

> [06D8:0C80][2014-12-03T18:24:39]i338: Acquiring package: aspnetmvc4vwd12tools_1014, payload: cabA3BBAEE7F3255814C4DE370C415391E5, download from: bits://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=427850&clcid=0x409
>   [06D8:15A4][2014-12-03T18:24:52]i000: MUX:  ExecuteError: Package (webdeploy_x64_en_usmsi_902) failed: Error Message Id: 2738 ErrorMessage: The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2738. 
>   [0254:2660][2014-12-03T18:24:58]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to install MSI package.
>   [0254:2660][2014-12-03T18:24:58]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute MSI package.
>   [06D8:15A4][2014-12-03T18:24:58]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to configure per-machine MSI package.

Did anyone who has met the same issue help me figure out? Thank you so much

Comment: Let me know if my answer works for you and if you need more help

Comment: Hi, faby. When trying to install Web Deploy 3.5 as a standalone application. I have got another error message: "The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2738". May you give me some suggestions about this? Thanks

Comment: yes, could you provide me some information about your system? version of windows? 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Let me know if that Microsoft fix works for you

Comment: Sure. Window 7, 64-bit version, Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3610QM CPU @ 2.30GHz 2.30 GHz. Hope it helps. Thanks, faby :)

Comment: Hi, faby. I did try Microsoft fix, but still it did not work

Comment: Yeah. It was the same problem

Comment: Did you try to reinstall the single component after running the Microsoft wizard?

Comment: Yes. After running Microsoft fix. I have tried reinstalling, but things still did not work.

Comment: I've updated the answer.. try that and let me know

Answer (score 0):

try installing it as a standalone program from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39277) and try to reopen VisualStudio

have a look in `System Requirements` section

> **Supported Operating System**
>  Windows 7 Professional, Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 2, Windows Server 2008, 
> Windows Server
>   2008 R2 SP1, Windows Server 2012, Windows Server 2012 R2, Windows
>   Vista, Windows XP 
> The supported platform is 64-bit for this
>   download. The .NET 2.0 Framework SP1 or greater must be installed.

if it doesn't work try this [Microsoft](http://support2.microsoft.com/mats/program_install_and_uninstall) fix. Run the exe that should solve some machine problems

if all of this suggestions don't work you can try these steps

1. Go to Start-->Run type cmd and press Enter
2. type `cd %systemroot%\system32` and then Enter
3. type `regsvr32 vbscript.dll` and the enter
4. next steps are because you have a 64bit version
5. type `cd %systemroot%\syswow64` and press Enter
6. type `regsvr32 vbscript.dll` and press enter
7. type `exit`
8. Re run the installer of WebDeploy

Source from [this](http://forums.iis.net/t/1219068.aspx?Web%20Deploy%203%205%20install%20fails%20Error%20code%201603%20and%202738%20) link

Comment: Hi, faby. The same problem still occurred.

Comment: try running Command as administrator. Click Start -> All Programs -> Accessories 
- Right click “Command Promt” and click on “Run as administrator”

Comment: which message did you get after typing `regsvr32.exe vbscript.dll`?